# Describing a woman with きれい vs. 美しい{うつくしい}?

Tags: word-choice

Please consider these two sentences (彼女 is a woman):

> 1. 彼女はきれいです。
> 2. 彼女は美しいです。

My sense is that #1 and #2 have the same meaning. Pronouncing きれい is easier, so I have just always said #1. And, I don't think that I've heard "美しい" spoken much, if ever.

What is the difference between #1 and #2?
Regardless of the difference, native speakers still don't say 美しい very much? きれい is what "sounds natural"?

Comment: Why do you think pronouncing `きれい` is easier?

Comment: @istrasci "きれい" is just 2 syllables; "美しい" requires making the "uh" sound 3 times in a row. So, my pronunciation of "美しい" is just clumsy.

Comment: @snailboat I guess I made a typo. I think both should be "は".  Whatever the case, both 助詞 should be the same I think.

Comment: The only place J-speakers might say 「彼女は美しいです。」 would be in the English class in junior high school where they are asked to translate "She is beautiful."  It does not have to be English but it would be a foreign language class, not in the real world.

Comment: @istrasci The best example I have of why "美しい" is "hard to say" is in the movie "魔女の宅急便".キキ definitely says "kawai!!!" and "kirei!!!!". But, there is not chance she said "utsukushi!!!". It is just a weird sounding word for me at least.

Comment: The usual way of saying that a woman is good-looking: 「美人ですね。」

Comment: I think that 美しい is a common word, although maybe less common than きれい.  I honestly don't think there is any chance whatsoever that a trained voice actor in a film chose not to say 美しい because it was "hard to say", but perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you mean by those words.

Comment: I think feeling-wise, it's the difference between saying a lady is 'pretty' v. 'gorgeous/beautiful'. The former I can say without hesitation as it is more casual but the latter is deeper, and can come across as more serious sounding. So it really depend on the situation and who is talking and if that person is in the room.

Comment: @snailboat I definitely agree with you. I'm just saying I cannot pronounce it. And, the sound of "うつくしい" does not conform to what I sense as the rhythm of spoken Japanese. So, I'm not good at saying it or listening to it.

Comment: @user312440 Please listen to these recordings on Forvo.  Note the pitch pattern of うつくしい{LHHHL} and that the second vowel is devoiced: http://ja.forvo.com/word/%E7%BE%8E%E3%81%97%E3%81%84/#ja

Comment: @snailboat To get this off the stack of unanswered questions, I'd just like to make 非回答者's short comment the accepted answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If you want to refer to a person as beautiful, would you use \[綺麗\]{きれい} or \[美しい\]{うつくしい}? What's the difference?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/99235/if-you-want-to-refer-to-a-person-as-beautiful-would-you-use-%e7%b6%ba%e9%ba%97%e3%81%8d%e3%82%8c%e3%81%84-or-%e7%be%8e%e3%81%97%e3%81%84)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking against a [this corpus](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/) reveals that 「きれいです」 occurs a lot more often than 「美しいです」:

```
きれいです: 228
美しいです: 47
```

So, it seems that using 「きれい」occurs a lot more than 「美しい」 when being used in an XXX+です sentence.

From personal experience, I would almost always use 「きれい」 or 「かわいい」 when commenting on an adult female before 「美しい」.

This **shouldn't** be taken to mean that 「美しい」 is not a common word, or not commonly used. Referencing the same corpus:

```
きれい: 6792
美しい: 6364
```

Regarding the meaning though, if someone did say 「美しい」 (or 「美人」) I would consider her to be better looking than 「きれい」.

Comment: "きれいです 228, 美しいです 47" doesn't really say anything about when it refers to a woman, though. "きれいな人" and "美しい人" have both roughly the same number of hits...